# Integration of Java application with OpenCms

Tags: opencms

I want to know how to integrate a Java web application with OpenCms contents. Is it possible to integrate a Java application with OpenCms?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible. For example you can integrate SpringMVC or Struts into OpenCms, or other tools like JForum, an open source java forum, which also supports single-sign-on (SSO).

You can find information here & a small sample OpenCms+Spring integration project:

- http://www.opencms-wiki.org/wiki/Integration_HOWTOs

Since OpenCms is open source and based on Java EE standards, you are pretty free.

Comment: See my answer and update at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13490509/what-java-based-cms-can-manage-existing-pages-content, it has the current url.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done successfully is to create a jstl tag library to connect JSPs in OpenCms to a business backend.

In my case it was done through a SOAP web-service.

Another advantage of this was that I could test and develop my code in Eclipse, without a dependency on OpenCms.

Deploying to production would then mean to deploy a jar file to the OpenCms webapp.

Yet another advantage: Since we put some of the view-logic into the OpenCms-hosted JSPs, they were versioned by OpenCms.

Answer (score 0):

We have integrated SprigMVC into an existing OpenCMS installation. Here is a description of how we went about that: http://blog.shinetech.com/2013/04/09/integrating-springmvc-with-opencms/