# integrating WebApplication and OpenCms

Tags: opencms

Hey I just want to integrate already existing application with OpenCms Contents.Let me explain a example:i have an application like Demo.war now i want to integrate sreekanth.war and OpenCms how can i integrate could u explain or provide some documents related to these OpenCms and Webapplication

Comment: This is an almost duplicate question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263558/integration-of-javaapplication-with-opencms/3266127#3266127

The details how to integrate depend on the app, I doubt that many people on here or the OpenCms community know of sreekanth, but generally, you would merge the web.xml logic into one file (if it's possible), adjust the servlet mappings if needed. That would be the start.
The rest depends on the details of the sreekath architecture, any possible conflicts of jar versions, etc. 
But this is more of a general Java EE question rather than OpenCms specific.

Comment: This would be a helpful resource: https://www.packtpub.com/opencms-7-development/book since what you're asking cannot be explained in a few sentences without explaining the OpenCms architecture entirely.

Answer (score 0):

You can run several web applications (war-files) on one servlet engine in parallel. That already is a simple form of "integration"...