# Intergration of OpenCms into spring webflow application

Tags: spring-webflow, opencms

I have a application developed based on spring web flow framework. In my application i need to display some advertisements for that i opted for OpenCMS. But Integration of OpenCMS into my application im unable to do that. All available tutorials are like integration of web applications in OpenCMS. Here my requirement is reverse. Any inputs for this will be grateful.

Here some queries i want to know.

Can we Create webservice in the OpenCMS? 
Can we call that webservice from my application jsp page?

Any inputs will be grateful.....

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Eventually a duplicate to [Integration of Java application with OpenCms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3263558/integration-of-javaapplication-with-opencms), however the question there is the other way around, how to integrate Spring into OpenCms.

Yes, you can implement web services within OpenCms, you can basically do anything within OpenCms that you can do with Java, JSP, Servlet technologies. You can deploy your own custom jars, taglibs, implement RESTful services, etc.

I think it would be good to explicitly know your difficulties or question in the very detail.

I mean, if you just want OpenCms to act as a web services back end, then it's not 'real' integration, then it's pretty much loosely coupled. Then, you just handle OpenCms as any other web services backend, not much difference. And this way would be pretty easy in terms of 'integration'.

Then, you would let OpenCms return json or xml, instead of html, by creating the templates and assigning them to your resources (i.e. structured content in OpenCms, using cms:contentload tag, but outputting json). That's "basically it". Therefore, not clear where exactly you're currently struggling within OpenCms, please let me know some more details and the current status of your OpenCms setup, experience, etc.

Comment: Hi @Mathias Lin thanks for your reply..

Exactly what i need is for my application, need to display some images and content ,those images i want to get from OpenCMS repository, Like RestApi call in Hippo CMS in there any thing like that in the Opencms that we can call directly to OpenCms Repository from the jsp page of spring application where i can display those images.

Need to call OpenCMS Functions from my Spring jsp page..

If there is anything like that pls let me know it will be very helpful for me

Thanks
Jagadeesh